# How to turn off notifications with onesignal?

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, onesignal

I already add OneSignal to my app. But how to turn off notifications with cordova (android)?
I tried:

```
window.plugins.OneSignal.startInit("[empty]", "[empty]").inFocusDisplaying(window.plugins.OneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.None).endInit();
```

and on button to turn on:

```
window.plugins.OneSignal.startInit("1234-123-123-123-123", "123-123-123-1-23").inFocusDisplaying(window.plugins.OneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification).endInit();
```

but it does not work.

Comment: setSubscription() is answer to my question

Comment: can you answer how you did this?

Comment: Nevermind, got it https://documentation.onesignal.com/v3.0/docs/cordova-sdk#section--setsubscription-